# Unity, powerup collision issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic, collision

I'm getting some issues with logic and the behavior that is happening in my game.

I want to implement a powerup and this powerup just stops that character for certain of time. So to do it I'm simply disabling his script so he does nothing. Now this is working but the problem is I can't find a way to enable the script back to him after 5 seconds. I want to stop the character for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You should be using `Invoke`.

It is extremely simple.

Something like ...

```
void ApplyPenalty()
{
    yourPauseSystem = true;
    Debug.Log("starting penalty..");
    Invoke("EndPenalty", 5f);
}

void EndPenalty()
{
    yourPauseSystem = false;
    Debug.Log("    ...ended penalty");
}
```

**Don't forget** the `Debug.Log` statements.

Note that ideally `ApplyPenalty` (and EndPenalty) should be

## ACTUALLY ON THOSE GAME OBJECTS.

actually put that code ON THOSE game objects, NOT here in the "collision object code". You get it?

So in your case, to apply the penalty, it will be something like ..

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
{
    if ( (c.gameObject.tag == "Character") )
        c.GetComponent<YourHerosCode?().ApplyPenalty()
}
```

you see?

You MUST use the physics layers system. You literally have to use it to make collisions in Unity.  you MUST use the "physics grid"...

[image]

to indicate what can collide with what.  In your comment you say they "won't collide" but you can absolutely make anything collide (or not collide) with anything.

Note that in practice EVERYTHING needs its own physics layer, in Unity.

Certainly your hero, enemy etc will all have their own layer.

Tip: certainly "enemy projectiles" and "player projectiles" need their own separate layer, both.

Comment: Well ... ok, but you should do exactly what I say  :)  The key thing my friend is that (see edit) your "penalty" code SHOULD BE "ON" the hero - you know what I mean there?  you need to move that code "to" your hero, you see?

Comment: fair enough.  onwards to fun!

Comment: you absolutely have to use layers, my friend!  it's a must.  physics layers.

Comment: it's just how it is.  you actually have to use physics layers.  every single thing needs its own layer, basically.  then use the PHYSICS GRID to decide what collides with what.

Comment: See edit.   You can definitely do that using physics layers - in fact you will have to!

Answer (score 1):

If NullReference is on this line `gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControls>().enabled = true;` is probably because you try to reference to a disable component.

Try to assign a var in Start() to the component

```
var playerController = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControls>();
```

and then use this to refer to it and enable/disable it:

```
playerController.enable = true;  //or false
```